# How WhatsApp users authenticate themselves in end-to-end encryption?

Tags: diffie-hellman, authentication

I read the WhatsApp Security Whitepaper and I want to know how a user A, which uses ECDH (Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman) to compute a master_secret, can be sure that the public keys for the recipient B used in the exchange belong to B and they have not been replaced by someone else.
A uses B (public) Identity Key, Signed Pre Key and One-Time Pre Key, all stored on the server at the moment of B's registration: how can A be sure that they are actually his recipient's keys?

(ECDH is an anonymous protocol, therefore authentication must be achieved someway else)

Comment: This has been [answered](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119573/how-would-one-verify-that-the-public-key-from-whatsapps-servers-belongs-to-the) over on Security.SE.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45607/discussion-on-question-by-m-elman-how-whatsapp-users-authenticate-themselves-in).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the way WhatsApp and many other end-to-end encrypted messaging platforms work is that your device generates a public/private key pair. The public key is uploaded to the server and the private key is maintained. It is typically recommended that you do an "out-of-band" authentication of public keys with anyone you want to communicate with. This is often done by meeting in person. You can display your public key on your device, which they can see what public key they have for you (from the server) and compare. If you both see the same public key, all is well.

The reason and "out-of-band" mechanism is needed is that you cannot trust the WhatsApp channel for security yet, since security is being provided via the crypto. In theory, if you had some other trusted channel, you could use that. But if you already had a trusted channel, why use WhatsApp (or any other application)? This is why "in person" is typically the way this happens. You could do it over a phone call, or maybe even SMS, and feel sufficiently certain that correct public keys were exchanged. The beauty of how these apps work is that they allow you to decide that. That is also the disadvantage. If users don't fully understand the implications, they may be more risky than they would be otherwise.

This public/private key pair is used to sign partial ECDH key exchanges. You upload your half, signed by your private key to the server. The person who wants to communicate with you downloads one of the partial exchanges, verifies it with your public key. Completes the key exchange and uses the resulting key to encrypt the contents of the message. They then upload the other half of the key exchange, signed with their public key, and the encrypted message. Finally, you download all that info and are on your way.

Comment: While WhatsApp is probably the best-known app for chatting on mobile phones and their improvements for security are quite good, it's worth mentioning Threema (as an example, but I don't know any others atm), where as a user you actually have an indicator about the authenticity of the other sides public key: If you just had in-band contact to someone, there is a yellow dot, and if you actually did an out-of-band verification based on QR codes, that dot becomes green. But one of the disadvantages is that (as far as a I know) the identity is bound to the phone, not the account.

Comment: Hi @mikeazo could you please elaborate on partial ECDH key exchange

Comment: @JigarJoshi, yeah, basically, with DH (whether it is EC or not), I can create a bunch of public values ($g^a$) that I publish on a server. If you then want to complete the exchange, you send to me $g^b$ and use my $g^a$ to compute $g^{ab}$. Turn that into the symmetric key to encrypt the message, and send the encrypted message to me. I then look up the $a$ value, use your $g^b$ to compute $g^{ab}$, and I can decrypt your message. By signing the $g^a$ values (e.g., $g^{a_1},g^{a_2},\dots,g^{a_n}$) that I've uploaded to the server, you have assurance that they are mine. I know the private value.

Comment: Thanks @mikeazo - If I understood it correctly, Alice sends set of public keys to central server, Bob generates one key pair and gets one of the public key of Alice and gets a combined key (using his and Alice's publickey) and calls it _secret_ the symmetric key to encrypt, now Bob sends his public key along with encrypted message to server, Alice retrieves that message and associates it with specific private key to decrypt - I don't understand how does it combine 2 public key to make symmetric key for encryption part and how does Alice actually be able to decrypt

Comment: Could you please provide an example, [I have asked same question here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41175/how-does-end-to-end-encryption-work-for-example-for-whatsapp) which you are helping to answer here

Comment: To understand how you combine two "public keys" to make a symmetric key, you have to understand [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange). The public keys we are talking about are very different from what you typically think of when you think about RSA, for example. Also, I provided an example in my previous comment. If you receive $g^b$ and you know $a$, you can compute $g^{ab}$. If the other party knows $b$ and is given $g^a$, they can also compute $g^{ab}$. From that shared secret value you can derive a symmetric key.

Comment: As to your question you linked to, if Alice uploads 30 of these public keys (we'll call them pre-keys), and you want to send her 31 messages (or 31 people all want to send her messages while her phone is powered off), you are correct. They can't do it. Some implementations I've seen get around this by allowing one key to be a long-term key that can be reused, but there are some potential security issues with this.

Comment: @JigarJoshi, I suggest you read the [Wire Security Whitepaper](https://wire.com/resource/Wire%20Security%20Whitepaper/download/) and the [SoK: Secure Messaging](http://ieee-security.org/TC/SP2015/papers-archived/6949a232.pdf) paper.

Comment: Thanks @mikeazo - I will get back here after reading those papers

Comment: @mikeazo Thanks for your help, I was confused with multiple back and forth demonstrated in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Cryptographic_explanation) - I wrote a minimal code demonstrating this partial key exchange trick [here](https://gist.github.com/JigarJoshi/4db9a9bbf40bab93a79eac22bad11d4b) if you could review it once

Comment: one more question: reading [whatsapp security paper](https://www.whatsapp.com/security/WhatsApp-Security-Whitepaper.pdf), it says under *Initiating Session Setup* : Server: _the recipient has not replenished them, no One-Time Pre Key will be returned_ and  Initiating client: _If there is no One Time Pre Key, the  nal ECDH is omitted_ How does it encrypt in this scenario ?

Comment: if public key is public - how secure is verification of public key (even in out of band channel) ?

Comment: it makes total sense that if we encrypt with it only the person with private key of that public part will be able to decrypt it, but here encryption happens over ephemeral key (pre-key)

Comment: one solution could be: Alice is attempting to send message to Bob, she does partial key exchange and sends the calculated secret encrypted with public key of Bob and then only bob can further proceed with deriving final secret - but again showing a public key (or some representation of it) on device is good for authentication ? (one could simply do social engineering there by writting similar client and with the crafted data on that screen) - there needs to be entire handshake for out of the band authentication of user - what do you think ?

Comment: please ignore above - it has to be 2 way handshake to finalize authentication out of the band